# Policy based Ipv6 route is getting reflected in netstat o/p

Tags: linux, routes

I am adding IpV6 policy based default route in table policy_default:

```
ip r add default via 2a00:9a00:a000:1190:0:1:1:2a00
```

Though the default route gets added in table policy_default, but when I do

```
netstat -rnv -A ip6 , the table shows the default route there.
```

Expectation : The default route is not supposed to be displayed in above netstat command. In Ipv4, the behavior is the same as expected.

Is there any configuration setting by which we can disable to display this default route in netstat o/p?

Comment: Sorry, but his Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://serverfault.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Also, use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output.  Good luck.